# Hibernate One To Many criteria doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "author_id")
private int authorId;

@Column(name = "author_bio")
private String authorBio;

@Column(name = "author_email")
private String authorEmail;

@Column(name = "author_favourite_section")
private String authorFavouriteSection;

@Column(name = "author_password")
private String authorPassword;

@Column(name = "author_username")
private String authorUsername;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Blog blog;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Post> posts;

// getters and setters
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blog")
public class Blog implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "blog_id")
private int blogId;

@Column(name = "blog_title")
private String blogTitle;

@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "blog_author_id", unique = true)
private Author author;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "blog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Post> posts;

// getters and setters
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "post_id")
private int postId;

@Column(name = "post_subject")
private String postSubject;

@Column(name = "post_body")
private String postBody;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "blog_id")
private Blog blog;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_author_id")
private Author author;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "post_tag", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();

// getters and setters
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "tag_id")
private int tagId;

@Column(name = "tag_name")
private String tagName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<Post>();

// getters and setters
```

The following data is presented in db:

[author-blog-post-tag-AND-post_tag-tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgMhV.png)

THE MAIN GOAL TO ACHIEVE IS: Find all authors which have written posts that contain appropriate tags.

I can do it using a SQL query:

```
SELECT  a.author_id, a.author_bio, p.post_id, p.post_subject, t.tag_id, t.tag_name from author a
join blog b
on a.author_id = b.blog_author_id
join post p
on p.post_author_id = a.author_id
join post_tag pt
on p.post_id = pt.post_id
join tag t
on t.tag_id = pt.tag_id
where t.tag_name in ('Football', 'Basketball')
```

And the correct result is returned with author, filtered posts and tags.

But I need to do it using hibernate.

So using hibernate I want to find all authors which have written posts that contain appropriate tags.
And all those authors with ONLY those posts which contain indicated tags (see above - 'Football', 'Basketball') have to be returned.

I wrote this code:

```
final DetachedCriteria authorCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Author.class, "author");
authorCriteria.createAlias("author.posts", "post");
authorCriteria.createAlias("post.tags", "tag");
Criterion football = Restrictions.eq("tag.tagName", "Football");
Criterion basketball = Restrictions.eq("tag.tagName", "Basketball");
authorCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(football, basketball));
authorCriteria
.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
final List<Author> result = (List<Author>)getConfiguredHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(authorCriteria);
```

and I expected to receive:

Author(author_id = 54) with only one Post (post_id = 26) and this post containing two tags ('Football' and 'Basketball') as I received it using above SQL query.

But the actual result is that I receive Author(author_id = 54) with ALL HIS POSTS PRESENTED IN DB (ERROR AND PROBLEM HERE !!!) and each post contains all tags which also presented in db.

[intellij-idea-debug-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cxoN.png)

Hibernate generated the following queries:

```
select this_.author_id as author_i1_0_2_, this_.author_bio as author_b2_0_2_, this_.author_email as author_e3_0_2_, this_.author_favourite_section as author_f4_0_2_, this_.author_password as author_p5_0_2_, this_.author_username as author_u6_0_2_, post1_.post_id as post_id1_2_0_, post1_.post_author_id as post_aut4_2_0_, post1_.blog_id as blog_id5_2_0_, post1_.post_body as post_bod2_2_0_, post1_.post_subject as post_sub3_2_0_, tags5_.post_id as post_id1_2_, tag2_.tag_id as tag_id2_3_, tag2_.tag_id as tag_id1_4_1_, tag2_.tag_name as tag_name2_4_1_ from author this_ inner join post post1_ on this_.author_id=post1_.post_author_id inner join post_tag tags5_ on post1_.post_id=tags5_.post_id inner join tag tag2_ on tags5_.tag_id=tag2_.tag_id where (tag2_.tag_name=? or tag2_.tag_name=?)

select blog0_.blog_id as blog_id1_1_0_, blog0_.blog_author_id as blog_aut3_1_0_, blog0_.blog_title as blog_tit2_1_0_ from blog blog0_ where blog0_.blog_author_id=?

select posts0_.post_author_id as post_aut4_0_0_, posts0_.post_id as post_id1_2_0_, posts0_.post_id as post_id1_2_1_, posts0_.post_author_id as post_aut4_2_1_, posts0_.blog_id as blog_id5_2_1_, posts0_.post_body as post_bod2_2_1_, posts0_.post_subject as post_sub3_2_1_ from post posts0_ where posts0_.post_author_id=?
```

How do I achieve the expected and correctly filtered result using hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You asked for an **author** which writes a blog about Football or BaketBall:

```
DetachedCriteria.forClass(Author.class, "author");
```

It happens that this author also wrote blogs about something else. So you get what you've asked for. In your sql statement you ask for a projection whereas with hibernate you ask the ORM to get the object (**author**) with its **posts** collection.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for reading and answering my question. I indeed appreciate time you spent. The main aim ( problem / issue ) I want to solve is - to get all authors which have written posts that contain appropriate tags. Result should return all those authors and only with those posts which contain tags (Football or BasketBall ) passed to hibernate. I dont need authors with all posts they have. Only posts containing appropriate tags should be returned for specific author filtering other posts. Do you know solution how to achieve this in hibernate ?

Comment: Also I tried to do it using org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef but looks like can not get what expects.

Comment: You could then select Post as your root entity, not author or create a [projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection)

Comment: I added answer below

Answer (score 0):

I tried using projection ( authorCriteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.PROJECTION )

```
final DetachedCriteria authorCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Author.class, "author");
    authorCriteria.createAlias("author.posts", "post");
    authorCriteria.createAlias("post.tags", "tag");
    final Criterion football = Restrictions.eq("tag.tagName", "Football");
    final Criterion basketball = Restrictions.eq("tag.tagName", "Basketball");
    authorCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(football, basketball));
    authorCriteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.PROJECTION);
    final List<Author> result = (List<Author>) getConfiguredHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(authorCriteria);
```

and the following result I see in debugger:
[image]

Ok that is correct and I can analyze those data and sorted them to Author->List of Posts -> with Tags to specific Post. But this is extra work in code.
I assume maybe hibernate has more elegant way to return filtered data I need or NOT. If no way then I became disappointed of hibernate. Then it is more convenient to use some spring jdbc template or mybatis or something like that.

Using approach "You could then select Post as your root entity" involves extra queries to db. Why we need to do so extra work ? Looks like hibernate is not flexible and useful suffice if it can not run query which I want and return results in way I prefer.